# Java JRE or JDK silent Update

Tags: java, jre, jdk

Is there a way to Auto Update JRE or JDK if an update is available?

### Background

periodically JRE or JDK says an update is available, I would like to do this check using Task Scheduler on system boot which is easy and then if one update is available it auto downloads and updates it silent(not sure how to do this one)